# Slowing down the application

Tags: java, android, time, handler

I'm developing an app which measures `time` and tracks your `location` and `distance` during a training. Everything works fine when the app is on the **main screen** but when it works in **background** and the phone is blocked the app doesn't work properly. I don't know why but the incrementation of seconds is slowed down.

There is my code which increment seconds, this code is in the service which is binded witch activity.

```
TimeHandler = new Handler();
    TimeHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(TrainingActivity.seconds!=0 && TrackerSeconds==0)
            {
                TrackerSeconds=TrainingActivity.seconds;
            }

            if(!isStopped)
            {

                if(TrainingActivity.running)
                {
                    TrackerSeconds++;
                }

        }

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
```

How can I avoid this kind of situation when the process of working of my app is slowed down?

Comment: Rather than incrementing the `TrackerSeconds` why don't you store the start time and then compute it in real time using the System time, then if there are any lags, it will all get worked out.

Comment: @ScaryWombat same on what in my head, im just 30 secs behind

Comment: I need the seconds to be shown to user on the screen during training, this solution has allowed me to achieve it.
Do your solution also allows me to achieve this goal?

Comment: @W.Kurek - there is no difference, you will be just showing offset ( time now - time when training started) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, when an App is on background you can't ensure that is going to have CPU time for itself every exactly second so what you have to do is store the time when you begin and then whenever you want compute that stored time with the actual time.

Comment: This solution works, but have you got any idea how to make the button PAUSE works properly? In the last version i just increment seconds only when the variable `running` was set to true.

Comment: Only compute the time if `running` is `true`

Comment: In this way i can only stop showing the progress of time, but in fact the time is still growing and if i click resume it'll show the time from the start whithout the substraction of time while beeing in pause state.

Comment: Oh, sorry i misunderstanded you, what i would do in this case is:
    -Store the time between start and the time when you paused
    -Set the start time to when you unpause the time
    -Set stored time to += end time - start time
    -Show the stored time to the user